# How to use loops to make sending data to a post array more efficent in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to ask for some help making my code much more efficient through the use of loops. Let me describe the scenario below before getting into the code.

I am developing a meeting scheduler application where users enter their availability through checkboxes which are connected to time slots of which there are 40. I would like to use loops to make the following 3 sections of code much more efficient.

SECTION 1

```
$id1 = $_POST ['id1'];
$id2 = $_POST ['id2'];

etc etc etc

$id40 = $_POST ['id40'];
```

SECTION2

```
if (isset ($_POST ['slot1'])) $slot1 = 1; else $slot1 = 0;
if (isset ($_POST ['slot2'])) $slot2 = 1; else $slot1 = 0;

etc etc etc

if (isset ($_POST ['slot40'])) $slot40 = 1; else $slot1 = 0;
```

SECTION 3

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO individualavailability (slotID, uniNum, available) VALUES 
('$id1', '$uniNum', '$slot1'),
('$id2', '$uniNum', '$slot2'),

etc etc etc

('$id40', '$uniNum', '$slot40')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stefan's idea  is good for checkboxes.
When you have some numbers or strings - you could do.

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $esc_key = strtolower(trim($key);
    if (substr($esc_key), 0, 2) === 'id') {
        isset($_POST[$key]) ? $ids[] = intval(trim($value)); : $ids[] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't 'group' the inputs?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="slot[]" value="40" />
<input type="checkbox" name="slot[]" value="41" />
```

In PHP you can do then

```
foreach($_POST['slot'] as $value)
{
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Stefan and Koredalin, your help is much appreciated....I will give your suggestions a try this evening!